# What is the average of values greater than 500 using averageif on macros excel?

Tags: excel, macros

I'm trying to find the average of values greater than 500 and put it in F2 using average of. I can't figure how to display the count of the number of rows in column 1 over 500 so I can divide it from the sum. A2=435.02 A3=340.38 A4=551.11 A5=230.22 A6=EOF.

So far I have:

```
Sub averageif()
    Dim rownum as integer
    Rownum=2
    Do
        If (cells(rownum,1).value>500) then
            Cells(2,6).value=cells(2,6).value+cells(rownum,1).value
        End if
        Rownum=rownum+1
    Loop until (cells(rownum,1).value="EOF")
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of rows in column 1 over 500, you can use the COUNTIF function.
In a cell that isn't in column 1, You can use the following formula.

> =COUNTIF(A:A,">500")

To Find the Sum of Values over a value likewise you can use the SUMIF function

> =SUMIF(A:A,">500")

Then you can find the average by dividing the result of the two.
The direct formula for this is

> =AVERAGEIF(A:A,">500")

Alternatively, a completed macro that find the average of values over 500 in column 1 is below

```
Sub CalculateAverages()
    'Find the average of Column 1 values over 500
    Dim count_over_500 As Long
    Dim sum_over_500 As Double
    Dim average As Double
    Sheets(1).Select    'Select the sheet where the data originates
    count_over_500 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), ">500")
    sum_over_500 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A:A"), ">500")
    average = sum_over_500 / count_over_500
End Sub
```

Or the straight AverageIF optimised version

```
Sub CalculateAveragesUsingAverageIf()
    Dim average As Double
    Sheets(1).Select    'Select the sheet where the data originates
    average = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("A:A"), ">500")
End Sub
```

Comment: And `AVERAGEIF` works the same way if you want to just skip the counting part.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thanks Modified with the straight averageif

Answer (score 0):

OP has had the opportunity to clarify, and declined it, so for the sake of others, there are essentially two possibilities:

1] The Excel version is commonplace (as implied by the generic tagging) hence has the [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) function so the following formula can be applied:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,">500")
```

Calculating this by SUM/COUNT does not make sense, specially if struggling to do so.

2] The Excel version is antique (Excel 2003 for example does not have AVERAGEIF).

Here the following array formula may be suitable:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(A:A>500,A:A,""))}
```

Either way a subroutine does not seem suitable. This OP might have use for a UDF, but has not said so.